# sort search result but keep the result - django

Tags: jquery, python, django, search-engine

I am stuck in this issue:

I have a search engine in my page. one can search and get results of more than 2 pages. I am rendering the pages with paginator. But the current problem is that once I search and sort the result, the search result will be distroyed. After sort, i am getting different search results.

the architecture is this:

normal search:

```
page/found-items/?state=bla&place=bla
```

sort on `page/found-items/?state=bla&place=bla` runs with `Jquery.load()` function to url: `/sort/?sortid=bla`.

in my views.py i have two functions:

```
def search(result):
  #search in db

def sort(request):
  #sort the search result, but how to keep the result after sort???
```

the code is too long, thats why i just posted the form of functions and urls..

appeciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python lists have a built-in `sort()` method that modifies the list in-place, but there is also a `sorted()` built-in function that builds a **new** sorted list from an iterable.